# Javascript: Filter out on an array of objects and pick based on key, not value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Im trying to loop through an array of objects, which have different keys. Is there a way that I can pick an object based on they key?

```
var array = [
  {
    "1400": "Accident and Health"
  },
  {
    "100": "Life"
  },
  {
    "1300": "Pension"
  }
]
var a = "100";
var pop = _.pick(array,a);
console.log(pop);
```

Desired output:

Life

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `in` operator.

```js
var array = [{ 1400: "Accident and Health" }, { 100: "Life" }, { 1300: "Pension" }];

var result = (key => array.find(item => key in item)[key])(100);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
  {
    "1400": "Accident and Health"
  },
  {
    "100": "Life"
  },
  {
    "1300": "Pension"
  }
]
var a = "100";


var pop = _.map(array, function(currentObject) {
  var b= _.pick(currentObject, a);
  if(!_.isEmpty(b))
    console.log(b);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash 4.17.2

```
_.chain(array).map('100').compact().head().value();
```